# Mysterious transfer of BC

Tags: transactions

1. Sent coins from one online wallet of mine to another
2. Coins were immediately credited from the first wallet which now has a balance of zero, but did not appear in the second wallet. Mt initial thought was that I stuffed up and entered the wrong address, but
3. There was no record whatsoever of the transaction OUT of Wallet 1 on the Blockchain, until
4. Finally, TWO DAYS later, a transaction record appeared on the Blockchain from Wallet 1 to dozens of different addresses, spread across 4 different payments approximately totalling my initial amount

Basically I would just like to know what happened, I'm confused as to whether this is my error or something else

Comment: What online wallets are you using? Different ones work in different ways.

Comment: From an account to an anonymising service. Note TO the anonymising service rather than FROM - I know some of these websites deliberately scramble transactions through a number of different addresses in order to increase anonymity. I guess it's possible the site I was using had this feature built in as well...

My main question would be why did it take so long for the transaction to show up on the Blockchain? Just a case of the website showing me a balance of zero for my account but delaying the actual payment (to wherever)?

Comment: I mean, what software / site were you using to manage your addresses and send your coins?

Answer (score 1):

If you were using an coin mixing service it would have sent your coins to many different places, to try to make it harder to trace.

Since the blockchain allows us to see where all coins go at any time, this is really the only way they can do it.

Without seeing the transaction (which defeats the point of you making it) I would say the system is working as intended.